# Error while using DataTable.Select() Method in Vb.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, datatable

I am using `DataTable.Select()` method to filer based on some conditions.

```
dtRows = m_dtTable.Select(String.Format("IdentifierID={0}", dtRow
("QuestionID").ToString))
```

I used the similar way to sort the data in different places . But only one place i am getting error.
Can any help me to find why this exception is occurs? Also help me to know why there is no exception in other places ? The values of datatable is filled from a stored procedure.

`Min (2) must be less than or equal to max (-1) in a Range object.` is exception I am getting.

**EDIT -- After the First Answer --**

I am getting exception not every time, but only some time that I cannot identify the scenario. :(

**ADDED -- After the First Answer --**

Thanks for the solution. :)

Note : m_DependantQuestionsDataTable and m_dtTable are same by its schema.

`colIdentifierID.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")
colIdentifierID.ColumnName = "IdentifierID"`

This is the type of particular column. There is also another column which is also similar type and there is no error occurs when I use it with the similar method.

`colQuestionID.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")
        colQuestionID.ColumnName = "QuestionID"` is the column and I am using like this. '        Dim strFilterExpression As String = "questionID={0}" m_DependantQuestionsDataTable.Select(String.Format(strFilterExpression, dRow("QuestionID")))'

Here there is no exception or error is occurring . So if I am choosing your solution I need to change the Filter Expression by adding `'` in all place in my solution where I am using Filter Method.

Comment: Yes there are records in that

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify the data type of the column you're filtering on and if it's a string then you'll need to add single quotes around the parameter in your filter expression:

```
dtRows = m_dtTable.Select(String.Format("IdentifierID='{0}'", dtRow("QuestionID").ToString()))
```

Comment: `colIdentifierID.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")
colIdentifierID.ColumnName = "IdentifierID"`

Comment: @Harie If the underlying data type of the column is String, I'd always use the single quotes; I'm a little surprised it would work if you _didn't_ do this.  It's possible that the DataTable expression evaluator will let you get by without the single quotes, but it's always best to be explicit with things like this.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, if you want to sort+ filter via the DGV, without need to repopulate the DT and DGV, you can use .Sort and .RowFilter of the DataView

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx

```
Private _DS As New DataSet
Private _DT As New DataTable
Private _DV As New DataView
Private _DGV As New DataGridView
Private _isFiltering As Boolean = False

Private Sub filterView()
    If _isFiltering Then Return
    _isFiltering = True
    Dim _SF As String = "price ASC"
    'Dim _RF As String = tableStructure.Columns(0).Name & " < 20" ' just an example
    Dim _RF As String = "price < 20"
    _DGV.ClearSelection()
    _DT.DefaultView.Sort = _SF
    _DT.DefaultView.RowFilter = _RF
    _isFiltering = False
End Sub
```